# issue with vscode-neovim navigations

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am using VsCode on MAC OSX.
I installed vscode-vim and editor works fine.
Now, I installed vscode-neovim extension and updated `settings.json` with below

```
"vim.enableNeovim": true,
"vim.neovimPath": "/usr/local/bin/nvim"
```

However, when I press arrow-keys in editor, I am getting below message

```
command 'vscode-neovim.up' not found
```

I checked the `Keyboard Shortcuts` see below entries for `vscode-neovim.up`, etc. like below
attachment.
[image]

Am I missing any other configurations?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after just installing vscode-neovim. It appears the current extension requires version 0.5.0 or later of neovim, which is a nightly/development release. On OSX, you can install it with `brew install --HEAD neovim` or see [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases) for releases.

You probably also want to uninstall the vscode-vim extension from VSCode: these are conflicting extensions, not complementary.